# How can I import IMDB quotes.list dump file into mysql table that each row contains text between hashes("#")?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a *language learning tool* from [corpus](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces) I downloaded. What I want to achieve is that user will enter a word that he wants to see the usage of it in `sentences` then php queried output will list `sentences` which contains the *key word*. It's very instructive for the language learners.

For that purpose I want to import all the text into mysql database then access it using **PHP**. I did it indeed but it's not effective, `sentences` is not properly populated and query time is too long.
Format of quotes.list is as in the below text.

```
# "Andromeda" (2000) {Pitiless as the Sun (#2.4)}
Tyr Anasazi: Am I mistaken
  strangers unlimited access to this ship?
Captain Dylan Hunt: Why yes
  closely and see what they do with it. There's something not quite
  trust worthy about them
Tyr Anasazi: You occassion bouts of deviousness never fail to
  surprise me



# "Andromeda" (2000) {Point of the Spear (#3.16)}
Tyr Anasazi: Well even crippled I would much prefer to assume the
  offensive than instruct the crew to make peace with their various
  and sundry dieties!
```

How can I import text between hashes into each row in *mysql table*?
Would you post any other idea that will ease my project?

**EDIT**: I aligned text into sentences using a perl sentence segmenter script " sentence-boundary.pl" 
Now I can't figure out best way to create table and load "aligned text" into table. I tried a few things such as :

```
  CREATE TABLE text
 (

        body TEXT

 )ENGINE = MYISAM
```

When I load **"aligned text"** using

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/Desktop/quotes' INTO TABLE text;
```

and make a query using,

```
 SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST('freedom' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

query time takes about two minutes.

I tried `indexed table` below but I was unable to load the text into it, body field full of **NULL**.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS text  (  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,          `body` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**EDIT2**:

I managed to load the text into body field but the query time is still too long.

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/Desktop/quotes' INTO TABLE text (body);
```

Would you help me with it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the main idea of my question gets offtopic  a bit, I made a working super fast sentence lister mysql query on quotes table at last. After completing above steps I applied fulltext mode to table:

```
ALTER TABLE text ADD FULLTEXT(body);
```

Note that it must be applied after populating table otherwise import time gets longer.

I wrote a php file in my localhost and I'm using it to access database and list the searched sentences, it takes less then 2 seconds to list about 2500 sentences.